# How to analyse the control flow of all recursive call in this program?

Tags: java

How to analyze the flow control of all recursive calls?
I use Netbeans and debug the program but in that we have to decide whether to step over or step into I want this to be done automatically, to understand the overall control flow..

```
static int [] MergeSortt(int [] A2)
{
    if(A2.length<=1)
    {
    return A2;
    }
int mid=A2.length/2;    
int [] left;
int[] right;
int [] result;

left= new int [mid];

    if(A2.length%2==0)
    {
        right= new int[mid];
    }
    else
    {
        right = new int [mid+1];
    }

    result = new int[A2.length];

    for(int i=0;i<mid;i++)
    {
        left[i]= A2[i];
    }
    int x=0;
    for(int j=mid;j<A2.length;j++)
    {
        if(x<A2.length)
        {
            right[x]= A2[j];
            x++;
        }
    }
    left =MergeSortt(left);
    right=  MergeSortt(right);

    result = merge(left,right);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(); You can analyze the call stack

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best way to understand it is by regenerating the flow in your mind ;)

But if that doesn't work for you then I would suggest some kind of logger or  System.out.println(). That would be the easiest way because it will log/print it in the order it is executed automatically. And with some good explanatory messages you can easily understand it and even analyze it automatically because it will always have the same structure.

You can get the stacktrace from Java or use the debugger to do it manually but it will be harder for you and for analyzation tool. By logging or printing you can make it in a good human/machine readable format that you prefer.